# How does one populate a column in Carto with calculated values that have rounded decimal places?

Tags: postgresql, carto

I am now able to populate a new column with a calculated percentage with this SQL:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET <newColumn>=subtotal/total
```

Could you assist me with the required SQL query to set the populated result to 2 decimal places only?

I have tried:

```
SELECT round(perc_gr10_11,2) FROM ctn_youth_education
```

which gives me a syntax error, and I have also tried:

```
SELECT round( CAST(perc_gr10_11 as numeric),2) FROM ctn_youth_education
```

which gives me (obviously) a selection of the table with the rounding applied.

However, I would like the values in the column to reflect only 2 decimal places, not just a selection of the table.  The purpose of this is for the pop-up labeling which looks weird with too many decimal places.

Comment: This SELECT round( CAST(perc_gr10_11 as numeric),2) FROM ctn_youth_education would work better if you just add all other columns into it: `SELECT round( CAST(perc_gr10_11 as numeric),2) as newcolumn,* FROM ctn_youth_education` . No need to create additional column and populate it then; unless your dataset is really big, then dynamic query would be slower.

Answer (score 2):

This solves the problem:

```
UPDATE t 
SET c = ROUND(CAST(c as NUMERIC), 2)
```